# How to retrieve original, unresolved (unexpanded) registry value?

Tags: powershell, registry

In the System Properties > Environment Variables > User variables > PATH contains:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\SysinternalsSuite;%USERPROFILE%\bin
```

The value can be retrieved with:

```
PS C:\src\t> (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Environment).PATH
C:\Users\lit\Downloads\SysinternalsSuite;C:\Users\lit\bin
```

Is there any way to get the original value without variable expansion? It almost seems like `Get-ItemProperty` needs a `-Raw` switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as many times before, has provided an effective solution in a terse comment on the question.

Indeed, PowerShell's **`Get-ItemProperty` / `Get-ItemPropertyValue`** cmdlets currently (PowerShell 7.3.0) **lack the ability to retrieve a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry value's *raw* value**, meaning the value as stored in the registry *before* the embedded environment-variable references (e.g., `%USERPROFILE%`) are *expanded* (interpolated).

**Direct use of the .NET API is therefore needed:**

```
(Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Environment).GetValue(
  'PATH',  # the registry-value name
  $null,   # the default value to return if no such value exists.
  'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames' # the option that suppresses expansion
)
```

See [`[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey].GetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_GetValue_System_String_System_Object_Microsoft_Win32_RegistryValueOptions_).

Note: `'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames'` is automatically converted to `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentVariables` by PowerShell; you may use the latter as well.