# Cannot run winget although it is in the path

Tags: powershell, path, winget

I cannot run `winget` although it is in the path :

```
PS C:\> $env:path -split ';' | sls WindowsApps

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps


PS C:\>
```

and `winget` is present in the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` directory :

```
PS C:\> ls $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\winget.exe


    Directory: C:\Users\sebastien.mansfeld\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---l        15/11/2023     18:13              0 winget.exe


PS C:\> winget.exe
winget.exe : The term 'winget.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ winget.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (winget.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\>
```

I was expecting `winget` to run because it's in the PATH.

Why is this not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**Fix your user-level `Path` environment-variable definition in the registry** as follows:

```bash
& {
  param($key)
  Set-ItemProperty -Type ExpandString $key Path (Get-ItemPropertyValue $key Path) 
} registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

- In order for future PowerShell sessions to see this change, either log off and back on, or - if acceptable - kill all `explorer.exe` instances to force a restart of the Windows (GUI) shell, using `Stop-Process -Name explorer.exe`
- You may also want to call the above with `registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` to fix the *machine*-level definitions, **however**:

  - *Only do so if you find the registry value to be of type `REG_SZ`* (instead of the expected `REG_EXPAND_SZ`)

    - Given your symptom, this condition is *implied* for your user-level definition (see next section).
    - Generally, it **takes extra effort to retrieve the *unexpanded* data stored in a `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-typed registry value**  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51776962/45375).
  - Doing so requires running *with elevation* (as administrator).

---

##### Background information:

If the ***process*-level instance of the `Path` environment variable** - as reflected in **`$env:Path`** - contains ***unexpanded* `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references** such as **`%USERPROFILE%`**, the implication is that the **registry-based definition(s) of the variable was *corrupted***.

That is, the **original `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-typed definition of the `Path` environment variable in the *registry* was accidentally changed to `REG_SZ`**, which **can easily happen** if you use utilities such as **`setx.exe`** or the **[`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) .NET API** to update these definitions.

- For a ***robust* way to update the persistent definition of `$env:PATH`** - which is lamentably cumbersome - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375).

The process-level value of the `Path` environment variable is the *concatenation* of the *expanded* value of the *composite* value of the `Path` values of the following registry keys, *in order*:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` (machine-level)
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` (user-level)
- Note that this implies that *machine-level entries take precedence*.

If the registry values were accidentally changed to `REG_SZ` (literal strings), *no* expansion of `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references such as `%USERPROFILE%` takes place.

Since attempts to invoke executables by name only (e.g. `winget.exe`) use the directories listed in the value of `Path` *verbatim*, a directory *literally* named `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`, for instance, won't be found.

Changing the type of the registry value back to `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (`ExpandString` in .NET terms), as shown in the top section, ensures that `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references are again *automatically expanded* before they're stored in the process-level `Path` value.